# Admin and Toolbar on the bottom, how to dropup menus?

Tags: admin-bar

I placed my adminbar in the dashboard and front end on the bottom, and I am having trouble on figuring out how to make the dropdown menus dropup.

Also when the site is viewed in landscape on mobile the adminbar stays on the bottom and on top of the content which is great. But when I flip the phone normal the admin bar stays in 1 spot when I scroll down. It doesnt stay on the bottom and on top of the content.

I'm trying to fix these annoyances.

Answer (score 0):

you can move admin toolbar to bottom using this function
add to functions.php in current themes:

```
function fb_move_admin_bar() {
    echo '
    <style type="text/css">
    body { 
    margin-top: -28px;
    padding-bottom: 28px;
    }
    body.admin-bar #wphead {
       padding-top: 0;
    }
    body.admin-bar #footer {
       padding-bottom: 28px;
    }
    #wpadminbar {
        top: auto !important;
        bottom: 0;
    }
    #wpadminbar .quicklinks .menupop ul {
        bottom: 28px;
    }
    </style>';
}
// on backend area
add_action( 'admin_head', 'fb_move_admin_bar' );
// on frontend area
add_action( 'wp_head', 'fb_move_admin_bar' );
```

or using this plugins: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/stick-admin-bar-to-bottom/

Comment: I already put the adminbar on the bottom. I need the menus for sites, myaccount to go up instead of drop down. And on mobile when a phone is being held normal for the adminbar to stay at the bottom when the page is scrolled.